# putting paragraph tags on content paragraphs

Tags: php, html

Im trying to put paragraph text around the paragraphs. This code pulls out the blockquotes from my Wordpress post and outputs everything else

html

```
        <?php
            $block2 = get_the_content();
            $block2 = preg_replace('~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~', '', $block2);
            echo '<p>'.$block2.'</p>';
        ?>
```

But it only puts < p > tags around the fist paragraph and not the others

Comment: Have your tried $block2=preg_replace('blockquote','p',$block2);

Comment: That throws up an error

Comment: How do you define a paragraph? Can you show some actual examples? @jeff's example I think would use `str_replace`, not `preg_replace`.

Comment: Basically all text in a worpress post I want to put in a pargraph. I want to remove the blockquote in the content (so it can be put somewhere else) and want to put all the text in paragraph tags. The images already post with img tags and the headers with h tags

Comment: I mean paragraphs. The text in the posts in paragraphs (when the ser hits enter creating a new paragraph in the editor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood this correctly, you could try splitting `$block2` by newlines, looping through the resulting array and wrapping each element of the array in `<p>` tags as you have done.

Currently, your code wraps the entire content of `$block2` in `<p>` tags, where I assume you wanted it to wrap the sections separated by newlines.

Example (I don't remember the exact syntax for PHP - sorry):

```
$split_block = split($block2, '\n');
for ($i in $split_block) {
    $split_block[$i] = '<p>'.$split_block[$i].'</p>';
}
echo $split_block;
```